# Why does the output of journalctl sometimes include 'skipping...'

Tags: logging, systemd-journald

For example :

```
journalctl -r
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-04-23 18:53:52 PDT, end at Thu 2020-07-02 10:40:23 PDT. --
```

lines removed by me for this post

```
 Jul 01 16:15:55 asus at-spi-bus-launcher[2801]: dbus-daemon[2801]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1000 pid=2539 c>
 ...skipping...
 Jul 01 16:15:53 asus rtkit-daemon[2551]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
```

How can I see what is skipped? Is this an efficiency feature of journalctl or some issue with my computer?

Comment: Yeah it is skipping the same line. Sometimes you will also see something like " ....skipping 14 lines... "

Comment: @Rinzwind so it is skipping over duplicate lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The skipping results form your pager. `journalctl` uses `less` per default.

> Those "skipping" lines are perfectly normal.

as posted by [michas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274549/more-less-skipping-when-searching)

Further:

> Searching for some string is much faster than displaying each and every line on screen. Therefore if you search for a word, less will scan the file for that word and once it finds a line it will display only that page of lines where it found the word.

> If you scroll back using your terminal you will see those "skipping" lines.

> If you want to go backwards in your text just use the proper keys like arrow keys. This will move you through the text as it is without any "skipping"s.

I also suggest to repaint the screen by pressing the <kbd>r</kbd> key.